# When using :input getting attribute value of input in question/context

Tags: jquery, input

I am trying this

```
var newNum = some new number;

$("#myDiv fieldset:last").find(':input').attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + newNum);
```

If an input field in myDiv is 'firstName' i want to rename it 'firstName15' may be!

How can i achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: whats wrong with above code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.each()`

```
$("#myDiv fieldset:last").find(':input').each(function(i, e) { 
    $(e).attr('name', $(e).attr('name') + newNum);
});
```

Of course if you are going to be incrementing the counter in the operation make sure you account for that, but if you are only doing one assignment, you can create a variable containing the element you are selecting and operate on that otherwise `$this` in the context above does not refer the element you are selecting.

Comment: Just another question now what if i want to append this new number in the middle of the existing name? :-( something like this product[newNum][fieldName]. Thanks!

Comment: I figured out the latter question myself; thanks alot. :) used .length -2

Answer (score 0):

```
var $input = $("#myDiv fieldset:last").find(':input');

$input.attr('name', $input.attr('name') + newNum);
```

`this` is not the input element in that context.

EDIT: I may have misunderstood your question slightly.  If your intent is to work on multiple input elements and not just one, use @Quintin's solution with `each`.

Comment: I think perhaps I misunderstood the question, although the solution I posted would still work for only one element it is not likely the most elegant solution in that scenario.

Comment: @Quintin After seeing your answer and re-reading the question, I think you actually understood and I didn't ... who knows!